# nopcommerce 3.60 slider image upload error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, nopcommerce

I am developing web application with nopcommerce 3.60.I am tried to upload image for slider image from : Plugins/7Spike-Plugins/ nop anywhere sliders / Manage Sliders. and i am getting error **"Upload failed"**.Its working perfectly on local host.Any thing i missed to set up on server or may be there is setting in nop-nopcommerce admin.Here is a screen shot.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your system logs? I means from System > Log ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the maximum upload file size and also write access to the folder in which the image upload

Comment: I checked all these things but not working.Its working perfectly on local.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.I just upload Image on local side and then publish local code to sever with uploaded images and latest database.So for now its fixed.